# Move with cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, 2d-games

I am making a game of paddle ball, I have designed and scripted ball under boundary.
I want to make a paddle more and that moves with current mouse position.
How do i get that?
This is my code of ball moving under boundary, I need a paddle at bottom.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body onload="init();">
<script>
var context;
var x=150;
var y=150;
var dx=2;
var dy=4;

function init()
{
  context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(draw,10);
}

function draw()
{
  context.clearRect(0,0, 300,300);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="#98bf26";
  // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
  context.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();


  // Boundary Logic
if( x<0 || x>300) dx=-dx;
if( y<0 || y>300) dy=-dy;
x+=dx;
y+=dy;
}

</script>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px dotted #111;" >
  </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to implement a `mousemove` handler for the canvas. Would it be ok for you to include jQuery?

Comment: You start the first `<body>` tag, and then add a `<script>`, then start **another** `<body>` tag, add your canvas and then end your second `<body>` tag? Why is there two? Why isn't the first one ended?

Comment: I can use jquery with mousemove, but how should i be sure that it would only be moving x-direction?

Comment: @ManojKumar just ignore the y coordinate from the mouse event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to your code

```
myCanvas.onmousemove = mouse_move_callback
```

Where `mouse_move_callback` is a function like

```
function mouse_move_callback(ev) {
  // Get mouse position
  if (ev.offsetX) {
    c_x = ev.offsetX;
    c_y = ev.offsetY;
  }
  if (ev.layerX) {
    c_x = ev.layerX;
    c_y = ev.layerY;
  }
  // Update paddle position
  update_paddle(c_x,c_y);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't redraw the paddle on every `mousemove` - the handler will be called very often, so it should execute very fast. Instead, just update the paddle's position. It will be redrawn via the drawing loop anyway, and the delay will not be noticable when redrawing every 10 milliseconds.